# Rails 3.2 Helpers or Scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, refactoring, associations

I'm still wading through Rails, picking up as much as I can.

I have the following associations set up:

```
Outlet **has_many** Monitorings  
Monitoring **belongs_to** Outlets
```

If I was in a **dashboard_controller.rb**, and I had the following loop:

```
@revoked_outlet = Outlet.where(:revoked => true)
```

And then in the view, I'm looping through each outlet.
However, in the same loop I want to grab the most recent monitoring where **:was_revoked => true**.

How would I do this according to conventions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view, try this:

```
<% @revoked_outlet.each do |outlet| %>
  <%= outlet.monitorings.where("was_revoked = true").order(:created_at).last %>
<% end %>
```

Good luck

Comment: What would be the best way to refactor this out of the view?

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on @Anil's answer:

- `monitorings`, trailing **s**
- I'd suggest to make `.where("was_revoked = true").order(:created_at)` a scope on `Monitoring`

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: How would I create a link to the first monitoring returned by the scope?

Comment: let's say your scope is named `was_revoked`. Then you would do `monitorings.was_revoked.first/last` (according to how your sort them)

Comment: You could even add a method on `Outlet`, something like 'most_recent_revoked_monitoring` that calls the scope on monitorings and return the most recent to you